# Long division, polynomials

Tags: polynomials

So I've been find doing ones where the polynomial exponents all counted down without missing a number, like: $x^3 + x^2 + 8x$, bu what do you do when it skips one, like: $x^4 - x^2 + x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write :

$$x^4-x^2+x=x^4+0x^3-x^2+x$$

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: @windy401 your very welcome :)